# How to check is Ajax in Mojolicious Perl?

Tags: ajax, perl, request, xmlhttprequest, mojolicious

how to check if the request is from Ajax Mojolicious?

I tried to use `Mojo::Message::Request`

```
use Mojo::Message::Request;
my $req = Mojo::Message::Request->new;
my $bool = $req->is_xhr;
```

$req->is_xhr it is explained "Check X-Requested-With header for XMLHttpRequest value."

But I don't see any value returned.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That means the value is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned value is a boolean, look at the example code snippet below:

```
post '/ajax' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $is_xhr = $c->req->is_xhr;

    $c->render( text => sprintf('Is XHR: %s',($is_xhr)?'true':'false'));
};
```

I have a created a demo at https://limitless-eyrie-46853.herokuapp.com/ajax